# как подключить ckeditor?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, ckeditor

[image: подключил ckeditor, все работает]
ckeditor рабатает но текст не изменится

[image: не изменится,]

```
<div class="content_day">
        <div class="content_day_info">
            <div class="filter">{!! $content_day->filter !!}</div>
            <div class="time"><p>{!! date('M d, Y  H:i', strtotime($content_day->time_create)) !!}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_day_content">
            <h2>{!! $content_day->content !!}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="author">{!! $content_day->author !!}</div>
        <img class="content_day_image" src="{{ url('img/dev.jpg') }}">
        <div>
            {!! $content_day->content_text !!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

$content_day->content_text - ckeditor должен изменит это

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вы используете шаблонизатор, но сама суть проста: например, у нас есть текстовое поле, которое привязано к ckeditor. У него id replace. На эту страницу вы подключаете два файла - ck_init.js и ckeditor. Последний вы получаете из скачанного с официального сайта, а ck_init создаете сами и пишите примерно такой код

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#replace').length > 0)
    CKEDITOR.replace('replace', {
        filebrowserUploadUrl : '/ajax/ckupload'
    });
```

});

Разумеется, нужно подключить jQuery. И, собственно, все. Потом из этого поля по ключу name получаете значения и обрабатываете их

Comment: var ckeditor1 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
 AjexFileManager.init({
 returnTo: 'ckeditor',
 editor: ckeditor1
 });

у меня  добавлено это...
когда поставил ваш код не получилось(не работал вообще ckeditor)